# How to access Print Driver settings?

Tags: c#, ms-access, printdocument

My engraving printer has unique settings for the printer provided by the driver.  I know this is common but I'm not sure how it works.

The print driver keeps overriding the DPI to 500, when I want 1000.

I'm using a PrintDocument object in C#.  How can I use code to access settings in the print driver?  I noticed programs like Access can save print driver settings "per Access form".  How do they do it?

Comment: you should read into WMI or find out if it is possible with [DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272/en-us)

Answer (score 0):

for loop below works for identifying device index.

```
    For i = 0 To (Application.Printers.Count - 1) Step 1
        Set printCycler = Application.Printers(i)
            With printCycler
                Msgbox .DeviceName
            End With
    Next i
```